# JsGrid Sorting Not working on Customized column

Tags: javascript, sorting, jsgrid

The sorting function will no longer work on column that is using `itemTemplate` and `headerTemplate`.

You can see a fiddle from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zzzfmpgt/679/).

As you can see, in the column "Client ID", the sorting works really well. But on column "Client Name", the sorting doesn't work as I am using `itemTemplate` and `headerTemplate` for customization.

Any workaround is really appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
$("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
    width: "100%",
    sorting: true,
    paging: true,
    data: [{
            ClientId: 1,
            Client: "Aaaa Joseph"
        },
        {
            ClientId: 2,
            Client: "Zzzz Brad"
        },
        {
            ClientId: 3,
            Client: "Mr Nice Guy"
        }
    ],
    fields: [{
            width: 80,
            name: "ClientId",
            type: "text",
            title: "Client ID"
        },
        {
            width: 80,
            itemTemplate: function(value, item) {
                return "<div>" + item.Client + "</div>";
            },
            headerTemplate: function() {
                return "<th class='jsgrid-header-cell'>Client Name</th>";
            }
        },
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`jsgrid`](http://js-grid.com/docs/#fields) **name** is a property of data item associated with the column. And on header click this `_sortData` function will call in [`jsgrid.js`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.js) for sorting data. And this `name` config will use here. So for this you have to provide this config other it will blank and no data sorting on header click.

Please search this below function in `jsgrid.js`

```
_sortData: function() {
    var sortFactor = this._sortFactor(),
        sortField = this._sortField;

    if (sortField) {
        this.data.sort(function(item1, item2) {
            return sortFactor * sortField.sortingFunc(item1[sortField.name], item2[sortField.name]);
        });
    }
},
```

In above code `sortField.name` as column config and it is must mandatory.

**DEMO**

```js
$("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
        width: "100%",
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
     data: [
         { ClientId : 1, Client: "Aaaa Joseph"},
          { ClientId : 2, Client: "Zzzz Brad"},
          { ClientId : 3, Client: "Mr Nice Guy"}        
        ],
        fields: [
          {
              width: 80,
       name: "ClientId",
              type: "text",
              title: "Client ID"
          },
          {
              width: 80,
              name:'Client',
              itemTemplate: function (value, item) {    
                  return "<div>"+item.Client+"</div>";
              },
              headerTemplate: function () {
                  return "<th class='jsgrid-header-cell'>Client Name</th>";
              }
          },          
        ]
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid-theme.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.js"></script>

<div id="jsGrid"></div>
```

> Another way you can make manually sorting on header click.

Answer (score 0):

```
Way to sort JS grid on column after grid load :

             onRefreshing: function (args) {
                fundCodeList = [];
                jsonNumLst = [];
                jsonNANLst = [];
                if(this._visibleFieldIndex(this._sortField) == -1 
                        || this._visibleFieldIndex(this._sortField)==1){

                    $.each(filteredData, function(inx, obj) {
                        if($.isNumeric(obj.fundCode)){
                            jsonNumLst.push(obj);
                        }else{
                            jsonNANLst.push(obj);
                        }

                    });

                    if(this._sortOrder == undefined || this._sortOrder == 'asc'){
                        jsonNumLst.sort(sortByNumFCAsc);
                        jsonNANLst.sort(sortByNANFCAsc);
                    }else if(this._sortOrder == 'desc'){
                        jsonNANLst.sort(sortByNANFCDesc);
                        jsonNumLst.sort(sortByNumFCDesc);                      
                    }

                    if(jsonNumLst.length>0 || jsonNANLst.length>0){
                        filteredData = [];
                        if(this._sortOrder == undefined || this._sortOrder == 'asc'){
                            $.each(jsonNumLst, function(inx, obj) {
                                filteredData.push(obj);
                            });
                            if(filteredData.length == jsonNumLst.length){
                                $.each(jsonNANLst, function(inx, obj) {
                                    filteredData.push(obj);
                                });
                            }
                        }else if(this._sortOrder == 'desc'){
                            $.each(jsonNANLst, function(inx, obj) {
                                filteredData.push(obj);
                            });

                            if(filteredData.length == jsonNANLst.length){
                                $.each(jsonNumLst, function(inx, obj) {
                                    filteredData.push(obj);
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if((filteredData.length>0) && filteredData.length==(jsonNumLst.length+jsonNANLst.length)){
                        $("#measureImportGrid3").data("JSGrid").data = filteredData;
                        //isSortGrid = false;
                        //saveEffectControlData = $('#saveEffectiveControlGrid').jsGrid('option', 'data');
                    }
                }

            }

//Ascending order numeric
function sortByNumFCAsc(x,y) {
    return x.fundCode - y.fundCode; 
}

//Ascending order nonnumeric
function sortByNANFCAsc(x,y) {
    return ((x.fundCode == y.fundCode) ? 0 : ((x.fundCode > y.fundCode) ? 1 : -1 ));
}

//Descending order numeric
function sortByNANFCDesc(x,y) {
    return ((x.fundCode == y.fundCode) ? 0 : ((y.fundCode > x.fundCode) ? 1 : -1 ));
}

//Descending order non-numeric
function sortByNumFCDesc(x,y) {
    return y.fundCode - x.fundCode; 
}
```